# SQL Query Formatter

Tags: postgresql, command-line, format

Are there any (Linux based) SQL Query Formatting programs/plugins/extensions?

I use PostgreSQL and MySQL but other DB's are welcome as well.

I can use a VM to test with but would prefer a Linux (Ubuntu) based solution.

I have seen a online version but nothing as a installable.

Eclipse Based IDE's are a plus as well

Example:

```
select f1, f2, fname, lName from tblName where f1 = true and fname is not null order by lName asc
```

to something like

```
SELECT f1, f2, fname, lName
FROM tblName
WHERE f1 = true
AND fname IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY lName ASC
```

Here is a online example:

- http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

But I would rather this be in a local environment

Related:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310188/free-sql-formatting-tool

UPDATE:

Looking at this:

- https://github.com/darold/pgFormatter

FINAL UPDATE:

While this might be an overkill JetBrains has a database IDE, [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/), which has some great re-formatting options.

Comment: Related: [Command line SQL formatter or beautifier - Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/85348/command-line-sql-formatter-or-beautifier)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[pgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/) comes with a built in query formatter. You would create a view to see the query formatted like this:

[image: pgadmin3 SQL editor with formatted view]

Similar in pgAdmin4.

Of course, unquoted mixed case identifiers will be cast to lower case. (But I would consider this a blessing.)

And noise words like `ASC` in `ORDER BY` will be trimmed.

And last but not least, the view would have to be valid within the database to begin with. So not *exactly* what you asked for. Queries are actually reverse engineered from the view definition.

Comment: Sorry i think you misunderstood the question, I can format this myself. What I'm looking for is something to do this in a command or IDE. Example: I would highlight the query and press ctrl + shift + F, this would auto indent, all keyword to UPPER, each command/keyword starts on a new line, etc... So if someone type or scripted this long query I just would like a quick way to format it instead of doing this by hand. Here is a online example: http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

Comment: @PhillPafford: Yeah, not exactly what you are looking for. The closest thing to a PostgreSQL query formatter I know. Doesn't mean there isn't anything out there.

Answer (score 3):

While more generic (SQL instead of pgSQL), fsqlf (http://sourceforge.net/projects/fsqlf/) is a command line or GUI program, open source, to format SQL.  It supports having a formatting.conf file which allows you a lot of flexibility in how the final product looks.

Examples:

```
☺  [wwalker@speedy:~] 
$ echo "select f1, f2, fname, lName from tblName where f1 = true and fname is not null order by lName asc" | fsqlf 

SELECT
  f1
, f2
, fname
, lName
FROM tblName
WHERE f1=true
AND fname is not null
ORDER BY lName asc
☺  [wwalker@speedy:~] 
$ vim formatting.conf # 2 character change
☺  [wwalker@speedy:~] 
$ echo "select f1, f2, fname, lName from tblName where f1 = true and fname is not null order by lName asc" | fsqlf 

SELECT
 f1 ,
 f2 ,
 fname ,
 lName
FROM tblName
WHERE f1=true
AND fname is not null
ORDER BY lName asc
☺  [wwalker@speedy:~] 
$ vim formatting.conf # 1 character change
☺  [wwalker@speedy:~] 
$ echo "select f1, f2, fname, lName from tblName where f1 = true and fname is not null order by lName asc" | fsqlf 

SELECT
 f1 , f2 , fname , lName
FROM tblName
WHERE f1=true
AND fname is not null
ORDER BY lName asc
☺  [wwalker@speedy:~] 
$
```

Answer (score 1):

[MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)'s query editor natively provides a SQL Query Formatter: you just need to click on the "beautify" icon as shown below (red circle). Note that it doesn't change the case of the SQL operators. (I [submitted a bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71459).)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Online SQL [beautifier1](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm)
  AND [beautifier2](http://poorsql.com)

Answer (score -2):

SQLinForm (http://www.sqlinform.com) is based upon Java and thus can run in Linux environment. They have an API and command line version which you could easily use in your scripts.